# OSRM route with bicycle profile won't return bike road

Tags: osrm

I'm trying to request bike routes from OSRM, but the routes don't use bike lanes.

I've set up OSRM server(v5.22.0),

```
./osrm-extract --profile ../profiles/bicycle.lua /map.osm.pbf 
./osrm-contract "map.osrm" 
./osrm-routed "map.osrm"
```

extracted a map with bicycle default profile and searched for a route that goes through a bike lane and still the route I got did not use any bike lanes.

Replacing weight between duration and cyclability or implementing the changes from #5092 didn't change the response.

The maps I'm using include all cycleway data. When routing between points that are only connected by a cycleway, the route is correct.

Seems like bicycle roads get a very low priority no matter what I do.
Is there something wrong with my setup? Am I missing anything?